# ros2 pkg list show cmake packages

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a ros2 workspace with both ament and cmake packages.

The command "ros2 pkg list" does not show cmake packages that I have built and installed. It only shows ament packages.
How do I get it to list cmake packages?

For the cmake packages, in package.xml, I use package version 3 and set buildtool_depend, buildtool_export_depend, and export/build_type to cmake.

I am assuming that is problem connected with failure of "ros2 launch package launch-file" failing on cmake packages. Have not tested the xacro "$(find package)" on cmake packages, but am assuming that would fail too.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341870/ros2-pkg-list-show-cmake-packages/) by [ananya.muddu](https://answers.ros.org/users/42686/ananya.muddu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to be detectable as an installed ROS package your package should do two things (which `ament_cmake` packages does automatically in the `ament_package()` function):

- install an empty marker file named `${PROJECT_NAME}` to `share/ament_index/resource_index` (see https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/83e1b8147e2eda7d805e45c163aea60230a4d160/ament_cmake_core/cmake/index/ament_index_register_package.cmake#L28-L29 and https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/83e1b8147e2eda7d805e45c163aea60230a4d160/ament_cmake_core/cmake/index/ament_index_register_package.cmake#L28-L29) and
- install the `package.xml` file to `share/${PROJECT_NAME}` (see https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/83e1b8147e2eda7d805e45c163aea60230a4d160/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package.cmake#L156-L158) which might not strictly be necessary for your use case but your package should do anyway.

In contrast to ROS 1 the presence of the marker file allows for more efficient queries what packages are installed and where.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ananya.muddu](https://answers.ros.org/users/42686/ananya.muddu/) on 2020-01-17**:
Thanks for the fast response. I installed the the empty marker file to the directory ament_index/resource_index/packages/.